# mp4 video shared from my website not showing on facebook

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-opengraph

I have simple share button to share a certain video to facebook , unfortunately only image shows but no video  here is my solution

```
   <meta property="og:url" content="https://meed.audiencevideo.com" />
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4"/>
    <meta property="og:title"              content="test title" />
    <meta property="og:description"        content="Test" />
    <meta property="og:image"              content="https://meed.audiencevideo.com/images/thumbnail.PNG" />
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url"   content="https://meed.audiencevideo.com/videos/good_job.mp4" />
    <meta property="og:video"              content="https://meed.audiencevideo.com/videos/good_job.mp4" />
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="398">
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="264">
```

What am I missing in my code?

Comment: Debug tool reads the `og:video` tag quite fine, complains about missing `og:type` though, and assumes `website` for that. Try changing that to `article`, and see if that changes anything. (Don’t forget to re-scrape.)

Comment: what do you mean to re-scrape?

Comment: Send it through the debug tool again, to updates Facebook’s cache …

Comment: There is however simply no guarantee any more that Facebook will display this as an inline playable video - the dialed back on the amount to which they do that a while back. So you can do everything right in theory, but Facebook might still decide to just show your link with the thumbnail picture instead of the video.